# How can i replace all the occurences of a field that has different values in a file?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace all the occurences of a field in a file, by null :

```
('azerty',  'en',   'TEST', '7',    '1-NOV-15 06.38.21.000000 PM',  'a184086');
```

In this case, i want to replace `'1-NOV-15 06.38.21.000000 PM'` (including the quotes) by `null`, this sequence is the key for me : `.000000`

Is there any way i can do this with notepad++ ?

Comment: What is consistent about the field, always the fifth comma separated value, always a date, etc?

Comment: The fifth field is always the date yes, and it's the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
'[^']*\.000000[^']*'
```

With:

```
null
```

---

This looks for a single quote, followed by 0+ non single quotes, followed by `.000000`, followed by 0+ non single quotes, and followed by the closing single quote. Replace all of it with `null` and your good to go.

[***Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/vY3oK4/1)

Comment: It's perfectly what i wanted. And thank you for explaining how you did it, it's really helpful.